# RegEx expression works on regex101 but not in C#

Tags: c#, regex

On regex101.com I used the following expression which returned a ':' and a number (e.g. ':15').

```
(?<=Total)(\s*\:\s*)\d{1,3}(?=h)
```

These are string examples:

```
Anne KowalskyTotal:15hPersonal data

2021-01-19Total: 2hCertificate
```

Unfortunately, my RegEx doesn't return a match with C#. I also tried runnig the RegEx method in C# with Multiline option but this also didn't work.

What do I need to do in order to make it work?

Comment: Can you add the code to the question?

Comment: `@"(?<=Total)(\s*\:\s*)\d{1,3}(?=h)"` put a @ before the "..." if you haven't already done it

Comment: Regex101.com [generates code for you](https://regex101.com/r/gLySzX/1/codegen?language=csharp). Also, you may just use `(?<=Total\s*\:\s*)\d{1,3}(?=h)` to get the number only in the match value in C#.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Was just about to say that there is a code generator to generate code for a number of languages including C#

Comment: Your regular expression returns ":15" and ": 2" for me. The [Multiline option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Multiline) shouldn't make any difference, since you are not using `^` or `$`